# How to erase securely apple sillicon mac?

Tags: disk-utility, ssd, filevault

I've searched several articles to find a way to erase data in secure on the apple sillicon mac, and found `diskutil` or `Filevault` things. As I'm using m1 mac, so the `diskutil` was not an option so I looked up about 'Filevault'.

However, before I turn on `FileVault`, I've already formatted my disk by mistake(yes, it's my bad). So after that, I turned on `FileVault`, and reformatted it again.

In this case, can I ensure that I erased my data securely ? Is there any posibillity to restore the data ?

Comment: Are you preparing to sell/give your Mac to someone else at this point? Or just wanting to secure your data? Also: I don't understand your second sentence. Apple Silicon Macs do use the `diskutil` command. How is it "not an option"?

Comment: As I know, `diskutil` command exists but it doesn't work. I forgot the exact error message but it was something like 'selected(which is `/Volumes/Macintosh HD`) is not writeable'

Comment: That's nothing to do with Apple Silicon: it's just the OS is on a non-writeable volume.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly: you should not need to 'reformat your disk'. You can just turn on FileVault in System Settings, and the existing partitions will be encrypted, with your data in place.

Once FileVault is on, then a 'secure erase' just involves deleting the encryption keys from the disk. Your data is still there, but it is encrypted with no key (and marked as free space). It is impossible to recover.

If I remember correctly, FileVault is the default condition when you setup your Mac.

In **System Settings > General > Transfer or Reset**, you will also find an interface for erasing all your content.

Note that now the OS and your data are on separate partitions, all user data can be erased independently of the OS; leaving a 'factory reset' Mac.